# Screen Flow - Configure Each Choice to get related Values

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow

I am creating the Screen Flow with Resource type as Record Choice set. IN the Choice Label I need the Parent object value. Getting Invalid error.

Created Record Choice set for contact object in the Choice label trying to fetch the **Account.Name** below screenshot for your reference.

Can you please help me on this?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: As you are showing Contact can you confirm why do you need label as Account Name?

Comment: My scenario is different, i have two picklists one for `EntityDefinition` and another one for `RelationshipDomain` by selecting the Parent Object in the entity definition need to display the child object for that in the second picklist.  In RelationshipDomain I need to get ChildSobject.label. To make the question simple i was asking for Account and Contact

Comment: Did you try executing the Query in Workbench `SELECT Id, ParentSobjectId,ChildSobjectId FROM RelationshipDomain where ParentSobjectId='Account'` Are you getting the result as expected. Based on this I can share the flow

Comment: I tried from the salesforce inspector its working for me attached screenshot in the question

Comment: Are you okay to have that in other screen component to show related object based on the first screen selection?

Comment: I gave that approach to my lead, but he want to show the child object in same page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143269/discussion-between-user3214361-and-saipraveen-kakkirala).

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments section this may not be possible in single screen element. It is possible in other screen element by storing the value which you selected in first element and then use that filter in second screen element.

[image]

Here selectedname is a variable which we are storing one user selects from screen1 as below.

[image]

But this would give ids for custom relations as ParentSobjectId gives the Id for custom relations. You may use RelationshipType field so it shows as below.
[image]

As you said you may have to use some custom code to implement this like LWC and onchange action for it

Comment: Bro, in the Second screen you are using `ChildSobjectId` in the choice label, this will return the ID not the label right? need to display `ChildSobject.label` like this.

Comment: No this will return the Name. Even in the screenshot which you shared in the question you will see that it returns Name for ChildSobjectId

Comment: will return Name if its standard object. If its custom object will return Id updated the screenshot in question

Comment: Yeah True. I missed it. Thanks for pointing it.

Comment: As we cannot get ChildSobject.label we have to use Relationshiptype. Updated the answer with same details

Comment: Yes but at the UI level I need to show the label, but while storing it should be the Object API name. If we use RelationshipName the value will be shown like this`AA_Temp_Child__r`

Comment: Yes that is correct. But that is limitation from the Record Choice set